# receive string parameters in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I send two parameters, a number (`$row ["inv_id"]`) and a string (`$status = "Close"`) to a function jquery php

```
$ inv_actions= <a onClick="invoiceStatusChange('.$row["inv_id"].','.$status.')" title="Close"><i class="icofont icofont-unlocked"></i></a>';
```

and I receive it in jquery

```
function invoiceStatusChange (invId, toStatus) {
    alert (toStatus);
}
```

present this error

```
invoiceStatusChange (532, Close) Uncaught ReferenceError: Close is not defined
```

If I send the number alone there is no problem, if I send two numbers, there is no problem, but if I send the number and the string gives the error.

Can you help? Thank you

Comment: Strings need to be quoted whan passed to js function. Without the quotes it is being evaluated as variable and thus the error

Comment: if you look closely, it goes in quotes ...`$status = "Close"`

Comment: That is only for the php assignment...not in the html. Look at the generated source in browser....there are no quotes there

Comment: you say, pass it like this `$ inv_actions = <a onClick="invoiceStatusChange('.$row["inv_id"].','."$status".')" title="Close"> <i class = "icofont icofont -unlocked "> </ i> </a> ';`

Comment: Need to move those double quotes into the php string...after `,` and before `)`

Comment: does not work either

Comment: What errors do you get now? May also need to do some escaping

Comment: `invoiceStatusChange(532,  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add backslashes with single quote

```
$inv_actions= '<a onClick="invoiceStatusChange(\''.$row["inv_id"].'\',\''.$status.'\')" title="Close"><i class="icofont icofont-unlocked"></i></a>';
```

OR

```
$inv_actions= '<a onClick="invoiceStatusChange("'.$row["inv_id"].'","'.$status.'")" title="Close"><i class="icofont icofont-unlocked"></i></a>';
```